# Using a function argument in a dataframe variable

Tags: python, pandas, function, arguments

I'm a novice python programmer and thinking this is a very simple task.

I'm trying to use a function argument as a value within a df variable when calling the function, but it is returning the argument address and not the argument value.

```
    def func_name(var_name):  
        df['varname']=str(var_name)  

    func_name(split_rand)  
    df
```

I want varname to contain "split_rand" throughout, but it contains <function split_rand at 0x0000025E4EAD9A60>.  I know that enclosing 'split_rand' in quotes will work, but I don't want to use that for alternative reasons.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning the string representation of that function name. If you want the actual function name, then you do `func.__name__`

I think you meant to do `df['varname']=var_name.__name__ instead` and I'd rename var_name to func.

Comment: Thank you!!  Exactly what I needed!!